# Cannot connect to pyftpdlib server behind HAProxy

Tags: python, ftp, haproxy

Having an error with my FTP server. It's been placed behind an HAProxy server that does communicate with the FTP properly.

Filezilla spits out:

```
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:  Disconnected from server
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

My HAProxy looks like:

```
frontend ftp
        bind *:21
        mode tcp
        default_backend ftp-pool  

backend test
        balance roundrobin
        mode tcp
        server ftp-1 IP_ADDRESS:21 check

backend ftp-pool
        server ftp-1 IP_ADDRESS check port 21 inter 10s rise 1 fall 2
# Individual backends

backend ftp-1
        server ftp-1 IP_ADDRESS check port 21 inter 10s rise 1 fall 2
```

As far as I've been able to find adding `handler.passive_ports = range(10001, 10250)` to my pyftpdlib server should enable passive mode.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Which part of the code Kevin?

Comment: I'm guessing you found that idea about passive ports [here](http://www.taitclarridge.com/techlog/2012/09/ftp-load-balanced-through-haproxy.html), maybe. It should work, but it's terribly messy.  FTP is a dreadful protocol to try to proxy, because of its design.  You'd be better off (not to mention more secure) to use SFTP.

Comment: Trust me I wanted SFTP in there, but the issue with dealing with cheap technology, the reason it had to be FTP is that the devices actually can't use SFTP (they're also hardcoded to only send out on port 21 which is a whole other issue).

Comment: In that case, you might find the [`mod_proxy`](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy) module for ProFTPD useful for your FTP proxying needs.